# Blocking direct access to index.php with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've managed to remove the need for typing `index.php` in my urls, but it is still possible to do so. I don't want that and want to prevent users to be able to access my application via urls like `/index.php/home` or `/index.php/contact` or even `/index.php`.

**Does anyone know how to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `.htaccess` write in the top

```
DirectoryIndex my_new_index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(my_new_index\.php|images|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_new_index.php/$1 [L]
```

Rename your `index.php` file to `my_new_index.php`

Comment: So you're suggesting to create an unguessable obscure directory index name so users won't be able to guess index.php?

Comment: I'm the OP. :) Okay, I see how this would work, but it's kind of  "security through obscurity", isn't it?

Comment: @Kriem if it will be other than `index.php` you could block from inside php but unless its directoryindex i dont see any option other than rename

Comment: @Kriem me also using this way.

Comment: Accepted as answer as it kind of fixes it. Though I'm not happy with the solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, then just setup a rewrite rule to redirect users from index.php to /

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ /
RewriteRule ^/index\.php/(.*) /$1
```

Comment: My reqrite rule: RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] - I'm still able to access index.php though.

Comment: Put this rewrite rule above your current one.

Comment: this will cause infinity loop

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Here's an example:

```
RewriteRule    ^foo\.html$  bar.html
```

Or you can use variables like so:

```
^hotsheet/(.*)$  http://www.tstimpreso.com/hotsheet/$1
```